# How to Retrieve Records from SQL Database with JSON Data Array in a Column Using a MySql Query?

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-8, mysql-json

I have a column `'tours'` contains JSON data structured as shown below:

```
[
  {
    "widgets": [
      {
        "name": "Calendar",
        "uuid": "db7308b5-ee0a-46d2-80bb-63dcb57f1152",
        "value": "2023-12-23",
        "system_name": "Calendar"
      },
      {
        "name": "Number",
        "uuid": "7cbdf159-7368-4db8-83e0-775cdd223131",
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Number",
        "uuid": "c8caa756-8563-4811-ac86-9dc0860832b4",
        "value": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to construct an SQL query that will allow me to retrieve records based on specific conditions within this JSON structure. Specifically, I want to fetch records where the "widgets" array contains an object with the "name" attribute set to `"Calendar"` and its associated `"value"` falls between the dates `2023-12-01 and 2023-12-31`.

Could someone assist me in crafting an SQL query to fetch the required records? I would appreciate an example using Laravel's Eloquent query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT test.*
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.val,
                      '$[0].widgets[0]' COLUMNS ( name VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.name',
                                                  value VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.value'
                                                  )
                      ) jsontable
WHERE name = 'Calendar' AND CAST(value AS DATE) BETWEEN '2023-12-01' AND '2023-12-31';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZzjPJAno)

Comment: Thank you, it's functional, but needs an adjustment. We need to make the indices $[0] and widgets[0] dynamic since the position of the Calendar can change, and $[0] might occur multiple times.

Comment: @Tariq Use `'$[*].widgets[*]'`